# Install mod_php on Centos for PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, chef-infra

I was using Chef to provision Apache with PHP module using the [httpd cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd). However, installing `mod_php` with that cookbook would install the PHP 5 module , even though I had remi set up to install PHP 7 (`php -v` outputs version 7.1).

How do I manually install (using yum or something) Apache PHP 7 module (`php7_module`) on **Centos 6.7**?

Comment: Guessing you are running apache2? Tried `a2enmod php7.1`?

Comment: Are you wanting a Chef solution or a vanilla install via yum?

Comment: "rpm -qa 'php\*' " output will help.  (php package provides the mod_php extension)

Comment: @Machavity A Chef solution would be better.

Comment: @daker in Centos there is no apache2, it's called httpd

Answer (score 0):

It is installing PHP5 because that cookbook is suppose to support only upto that. If you want a change, you can go and change/update/wrapper the module_helper.rb file for your environment and test it out.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd/blob/master/libraries/httpd_module.rb